# Slim down an ios backup file

Tags: ios, itunes, backup

My 32gb iPhone is irreversibly broken but I have an encrypted backup on iTunes (not iCloud). I want to load it onto my older 16gb iPhone but it's too large. I've found some software that lets you browse encrypted backup files but I need something that will let me browse it and delete large media files to slim it down to <16gb. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iMazing](https://imazing.com/iphone-backup-browser-extractor) works with iOS 11 and allows you to slim down encrypted backups. You

> With iMazing, your backups become fully editable, even if they are
>   encrypted.

---

> Advanced users enjoy a complete toolbox for browsing and editing
>   backups.
>
> - Browse the file system of iTunes and iMazing backups
> - Extract any file or folder
> - Edit backup files, or add files to backups
> - Encrypted backups are fully supported (password required!)

I have used iMazing in the past and for full and partial restores of iPhones and iPads.

Answer (score 0):

[**iBackupBot**](http://www.icopybot.com/itunes-backup-manager.htm) lets you open and modify iOS backups before restoring with iTunes. You can also use iBackupBot's built-in restore function to restore individual containers or other data without restoring the whole backup, but I haven't tested whether this still works iOS 11.

Comment: From what I know it cannot edit encrypted backups for restore later.